# How to create sub-sub branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging

When I create a branch on existed sub-branch I get error like this:

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/dev/mine/test': 'refs/heads/dev/mine' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/dev/mine/test'
```

If there was no sub branch "dev/mine" then I can create "dev/mine/test".

If "dev/mine" branch already exists, how can I create "dev/mine/test" branch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+cannot+lock+ref+exists%3B+cannot+create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Pretend that branch names are filenames; a `/` separated component can either be a "directory" or a "file". If you've created a branch named `dev/mine`, then `mine` is a "file" -- that is, it cannot contain any child entries.

So you can create `dev/mine/feature1`, `dev/mine/test`, etc., as long as you don't create `dev/mine` first.

You can always rename a branch if you decide you've picked the wrong naming strategy:

```
git branch -m dev/mine dev/mine/<whatever>
```

Comment: The "pretend" part becomes quite real when you look at `.git/refs/heads`, where the branch names are represented as an actual directory/file tree.